# Changing img src attr issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

At this current iteration, I have it where if a user clicks on an image thumbnail, the thumbnail image displays in a different div (the main div) and in doing so, it rewrites the main div img src attr with the thumbnail img attr minus the "-thumbnail". This part is good, or at least I believe it is.

With that said, after the user clicks on a thumbnail and the main div img appears, it lingers...and what I mean by lingers is that for example, if a user closes the div and re-opens it or another div just like it, the last image shows (stays) when it shouldn't in the main div. Instead, it should be showing the first thumbnail img in the main div...

Any suggestions is appreciated and below is what I currently have (or at least a portion of it). There is a lot more, but below is the main stuff that's giving me troubles...

The HTML part is within a div class called "t_1". I have 24 of these..."t_1", "t_2", "t_3" respectively. And within this class, I have what is posted below in all using the same div classes. The only difference is the folder names in the img tag.

So, when a user clicks on that thumbnail and that thumbnail image gets rewritten so that it can be displayed in the main div "t_main_screenshot", all is good...but then, if the user clicks out of the "t_1" etc. divs, and opens up another "t_2", that last image thumbnail that was clicked previously shows in the main div (t_main_screenshot) instead of the first image thumbnail for what should be in "t_2"...

Hopefully this is a bit better in clarity...It's kind of hard to explain.

HTML:

```
<div class="t_main_screenshot">
    <img src="_framework/images/slides/simplicity/2.png" alt="" title="" />
</div>

<div class="t_thumbnail_wrapper">
    <div class="t_thumbnail active">
        <img src="_framework/images/slides/simplicity/2-thumbnail.png" alt="" title="" />
    </div>
    <div class="t_thumbnail">
        <img src="_framework/images/slides/simplicity/4-thumbnail.png" alt="" title="" />
    </div>
    <div class="t_thumbnail">
        <img src="_framework/images/slides/simplicity/6-thumbnail.png" alt="" title="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/JQuery:

```
$('.t_thumbnail').click(function() {
    $('.t_thumbnail').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var thumbNail = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

    $('.t_main_screenshot img').fadeOut(0, function() {
        $(this).fadeIn().css('animation','scale-in .75s ease-in 0s forwards')[0].src = thumbNail.replace('-thumbnail', '');
    });
});
```

Comment: So I would iterate my understanding: You have divs with image and 1 main div. Clicking on these divs would set its image as main. But when user clicks on second div, this image is not updated. Am I right?

Comment: Close. I edited my original post.  Hopefully by doing so, it's more understandable...

Comment: Have tried replacing  selected image first and then do `fadeIn()` and `css()`?

Comment: BCoder, I think I need an `if/else` statement somewhere but I'm not entirely sure how to accomplish this...

Comment: try this : `$(this).attr('src',thumbNail.replace('-thumbnail', '')).fadeIn().css('animation','scale-in .75s ease-in 0s forwards');`

Comment: @BCoder, this does the exact same thing it currently is doing...In other words, sadly this didn't work...

Comment: Put some delay between changing image and animate. As image load takes some time and css works faster!

Comment: Can you please show how you are creating modal. Have you tried to destroy the modal on close and then open the new one.

Comment: I don't think that will matter...or at the very least, fix my issue at hand.  This is a hard thing to explain...Basically, if a user clicks on a thumbnail image, the main image changes to that thumbnail - and the image src attr changes (or is rewritten).  This is where the issue lies...as the user closes the overlay, and opens up a different one, the last thumbnail image they clicked on appears as the main image in the second overlay, etc...it's as if it's rewritting the src attr for the main image on the second (and so forth) overlay when it shouldn't be...

Comment: Try to trigger click of first thumbnail every time the modal box open

Comment: Your `src` rewrite is working fine. Just put a delay or One more thing you need to do is remove `animate` value before changing the image and then do you what are doing normally.

Comment: @Master.Deep, how would I go about doing that...I think I need an `is/else` statement somewhere but not sure how to accomplish that...

Comment: @BCoder, removing the animate value?  Not sure what you mean by that...if you meant the `css();` doing that wouldn't matter in this case...As for adding a delay...that too wouldn't matter (or at least I don't think it would)...Since whatever thumbnail is clicked last rewrites the main image src attr. - for some odd reason, it is remembering that for all other modal overlays main image...and that image is what is being displayed...It should be the first thumbnail image displayed for the main image in whatever overlay you are in but it's not...

Comment: Can you please update the code you have done on click of the magnifier button, on which the modal is being opened?

Comment: remove comma from each code like `$('#main-overlay, .t_1').show();` and make it `$('#main-overlay  .t_1').show();` . And also put a relative parent class for each like .t_1 for first. E.G. `$('.t_1').find(' .t_main_screenshot img')`

Comment: @BCoder, I don't think you fully understand what's giving me issues here...the tid bit of JS I provided in my original post is what's giving me issues.  Due to the thumbnail images (once clicked) being rewritten to be displayed as the main image, this is (for some reason) being applied to all...And all being all other modal overlay main images...Which causes the main image in whatever overlay you are in to display what thumbnail image was last clicked in the last overlay you were in since that thumbnail image was written...

Comment: It needs to be that in each overlay, the main image shows the first thumbnail image, not the thumbnail image that was rewritten in the last overlay you were in...

Comment: Therefore, I'm fairly sure I need an `if/else` statement - I just do not know how to go about doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```js
$('.t_thumbnail').click(function() {
 $('.t_thumbnail').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');
 
 var thumbNail = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
 
 $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.t_main_screenshot').children('img').fadeOut(0, function() {
  $(this).fadeIn().css('animation','scale-in .75s ease-in 0s forwards')[0].src = thumbNail.replace('-thumbnail', '');
 });
});
```

As you are updating directly on *.t_main_screenshot* class. So it will update all places, in this case in all your modals .t_1, .t_2, ...etc.

Comment: This is EXTREMELY close!  Now though, something I overlooked...the `removeClass` and `addClass` for the `active` state of the thumbnail image doesn't seem to be working right...

Comment: You can put default `active` for each container's first thumbnail on load of modal.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  I have it stated on the first thumbnail image of every modal overlay in my html file...The active state works if I do not click on any thumbnail images in any modal overlay, but when I do, it doesn't seem to want to apply...for example, open up any first overlay, select a thumbnail image - things are working as intended - but then when you close out and open up a different overlay, the `active` state (even though mentioned in html) doesn't seem to want to apply itself...

Comment: Btw, I selected your answer as the correct one since it solved my first issue!  I want to thank you for helping me out with this one...

Comment: Figured it out...Instead of using `$('.t_thumbnail').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');` - I changed those 2 lines to this: `$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');` and it seems to be working now!

Comment: Thanks for appreciation. For `active` , the main issue was you were applying `removeClass` on `.t_thumbnail` generally. So It was removing 'active' from hidden modal thumbs too. Whatever now, glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.screenshots_1').click(function() {
    $('.t_main_screenshot img').find('img').attr('src' , "");
});
```

This will help you to initialize the main screenshot on modal screenshot icon click.

Comment: Your code is not general Meanwhile you try the above code I will sought out your code to make it more generic

Comment: This didn't work, and what exactly do you mean by it's not general?

Comment: You are using t_1, t_2 ... so many classes for each time open a new modal.Instead of this place a common modal and on each click append new images to it destroying the previously appended images.So for each time when you click on screenshot link the same modal will launch with different set of images.which will append dynamically to it.

Comment: This will solve many issue. You can create as many modal as you want. Second, will solve your issue of previous modal image appearing (As before opening a new modal you will remove all images from it).Third it will make code beautiful.